Is is possible to serialize and imported log class in java?
I have question for you...
I have this java app that I am trying to run on a jboss EAP 74 cluster. I am trying to serialize the session data, and I have an issue with the log setup.....
I have a tone of the log files with a setup similar to that below....
package com.company.myapp.bean.common;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.company.jfoundation.log.Log;

public abstract class myappBaseBean extends BaseBean {

    public String moduleItemAction() {

        ...

        if (Log.ON) {
            this.log.fine("********* MODULE ITEM ACTION INVOKED **********");
        }
        Map<String, String> requestParamMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap();

        String moduleItemName = requestParamMap.get("itemName");
        String beanName = requestParamMap.get("beanName");

        if (Log.ON) {
            this.log.fine("moduleItemName---> " + moduleItemName);
            this.log.fine("beanName---> " + beanName);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected  List<ScreenDTO> fetchScreenList( String modCode) {
        Collection screenList = null;
        try {

            this.adminBI = this.getAdminService();
        }
        catch ( ServiceLocatorException sLocatorExp) {
            this.setError(true);
            this.setSuccess(false);
            new ErrorHandler(sLocatorExp, this.resourceBundle);
            this.log.error(this.getClass().getName(), "", sLocatorExp);
        }
    }

    ...

}

I tried to just serialize the classs, with a simple implements statements

import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class myappBaseBean extends BaseBean implements java.io.Serializable {


}


, but I cannot seem to get around the error ...

18:28:04,506 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (default task-18) ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': java.io.NotSerializableException: com.company.jfoundation.log.Log
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:278)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)

Is there a quick and dirty way to serialize the imported log function, or am I looking at a serious refactor or this app to get the sessions cached.
Ta,
X
P.S. - Please don't get hung up on the import of the log module. The module can be anything, I was just wondering if there was a way to mark an imported module "whatever it might be " as serializable during the import?

How are we supposed to know what com.company.jfoundation.log.Log is?

Where is the log variable defined? It should likely be made transient  and initialized in the readResolve() method.
